# Mac Command failed: codesign --sign

Tags: electron, electron-builder, code-signing-certificate

I want to release the electron app on mac, and I have a developer account, which gives me a
valid code signing certificate. The first certificate I created worked fine until I forgot my keychain password and try to reset it by creating a new password. After changing the password, I created a new certificate which gave me a challenge; however, I tried to run "electron-builder -m" to create a new dmg file, giving me the below error.

*⨯ Command failed: codesign --sign 10B5CDF2F53C606C4E1DC2E7331AD595210D5420 --force --timestamp --options runtime --entitlements /Users/macbookpro/Desktop/twitter_tracker/node_modules/app-builder-lib/templates/entitlements.mac.plist /Users/macbookpro/Desktop/twitter_tracker/dist/mac/Twitter Tracker.app/Contents/Frameworks/Electron Framework.framework/Versions/A/Resources/af.lproj/locale.pak
/Users/macbookpro/Desktop/twitter_tracker/dist/mac/Twitter Tracker.app/Contents/Frameworks/Electron Framework.framework/Versions/A/Resources/af.lproj/locale.pak: errSecInternalComponent
failedTask=build*

I've tried to delete all node_module files and create new ones, but they did not work.

Comment: it seems that there might be an issue with the code signing process due to the keychain :) try to check your Keychain Access

Answer (score 0):

In order to sign the macOS Electron application properly, you need to unlock the keychain first with sudo permissions. In order to do so you need to unlock it first.

You can unlock it with this command:

```
security unlock-keychain -p "[Keychain Password]" "$HOME/Library/Keychains/[Keychain Name.keychain]"
```

Just run it is some pre-action before you sign your Electron application.